# why my code seems fine but shows WA in Codechef contest also why the code taking N as a string doesn't give WA

Tags: c++

For a given integer N . Write a program to obtain the sum of the first and last digits of this number.

INPUT:
The first line contains an integer T, the total number of test cases. Then follow T lines, Each line contains an integer N.

OUTPUT:

For each test case, display the sum of first and last digits of N in a new line.
CONSTRAINTS:
1≤T≤1000
1≤N≤106

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int T;
     cin>>T;
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
      int N;
      cin>>N;

      int last=N%10;
      int first=0;
      while(N!=0)
       {
           first=N%10;
            N=N/10;
       }
   

      cout<<first+last<<"\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: What does `WA` mean? Whizzing aeroplanes? Please provide a [mre] with inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs

Comment: What is the expected output if `N` is less than 10, 3 for example? 6 or 3? Your code gives 3.

Comment: @AlanBirtles WA refers to "Wrong Answer" while submitting my code in codechef contest and u can see the problem stated above my code....My code runs fine still having this WA issue i don't know why.

Comment: @Damien u had it wrong.....my code gives 6 for N=3.

Comment: Effectively, you get 6. But is it the correct answer? And what is the maximum value of `N` ? Information is missing in your post to check your code.

Comment: @Damien i have updated my post pls check now ....btw the problem is while submitting my code I get wrong answer (WA) in codechef. but my code seems fine for all sample test cases.

Comment: Could you provide the link to the problem?

Comment: @Damien https://www.codechef.com/CMND2021/problems/FLDSUM....

Comment: Very surprising. I tried several codes similar to your code, no one works. A similar version with a  `std::string` works (i.e. accepted by CodeChef). I could not find any input, for which the results of the two codes were different.